# Failed to evaluate expression from inside of PreAuthorize during tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-test

I am trying to implement authorization for app endpoints. I am working on using custom methods inside `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {
    private final TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PreAuthorize("@SecurityService.hasAccessToUser(#userId)")
    List<TestDTO> getUserData(@PathVariable String userId) {
        return testService.fetchUserData(userId);
    }
}
```

*sidenote - presented below `hasAccessToUser` method could be replaced by simply using `@PreAuthorize("authorization.principal == #userId")` but it's just a stripped-down version of SecurityService*

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityService {

    private Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    private String getUserId() {
        return (String) getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    public boolean hasAccessToUser(String userId) {
        return getUserId().equals(userId);
    }
}
```

This authorization implementation works well on launched application, BUT it breaks while testing:

```
@WebMvcTest(TestController.class)
public class TestControllerTest {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "/test";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private TestService testService;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @MockBean
    private TestRepository testRepository;


    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void shouldGetUserDataGivenUserId() {
        mockMvc.perform(asUser(get(BASE_URL + "/" + TEST_USER_ID)))
                .andExpect(status().is(Response.SC_OK));

        verify(testService).fetchUserData(TEST_USER_ID);
    }
}
```

When I look into a body of a response to the failed request it has lengthy log ending with:

```
Internal Server Error: Failed to evaluate expression '@SecurityService.hasAccessToUser(#userId)'"}]
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers.lambda$string$4(ContentResultMatchers.java:148)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
 at com.test.controller.TestControllerTest.shouldGetUserDataGivenUserId(TestControllerTest.java:87)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
```

So, Spring does not recognize `@SecurityService` while running tests. Is there any way of making `@SecurityService` work inside `@PreAuthorize` during tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `@SecurityService.hasAccessToUser(#userId)` will look for a bean with the name `SecurityService` . But you are now using `@MockBean` to define this bean which by default its bean name will be auto generated.  There are no beans which the name is `SecurityService` and so it throws this error.

You can explicitly configure its bean name by :

```java
   @MockBean(name="SecurityService")
   private SecurityService securityService;
```

which should solve your problem.

But better yet , don't mock `SecurityService` because it is a part of your application security setting and is not a kind of collaborator or dependency of the controller under test. Use the real instance can make the test case more close to the actual production codes.

```
@WebMvcTest(TestController.class)
@Import({TestController.Config.class})
public class TestControllerTest {
     @Configuration
     public static class Config {
        @Bean(name="SecurityService")
        public SecurityService securityService() {
            return new SecurityService();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the second way.

The first one makes the error ("failed to evaluate") go away but `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` during evaluation inside `hasAccessToUser()` does not hold expected user credentials. So, all requests were getting 403-forbidden.

The second way works like a charm! Good to know how to use beans in non-mocking way, too : )